# Should I use Gorilla Glue or Crazy Glue for broken off handle of a ceramic mug?

Tags: repair, adhesive

I have a ceramic mug that a handle broke off of.

Between Gorilla Glue and Crazy glue, is there a difference and if so, which one is better?

My main criteria, in descending order of importance, are:

- Non-toxicity long term. It's a mug people drink from.
- Dishwasher safety long term (don't much care about microwave safety)
- Physical durability of repair spot.
- Requirement for extra-strong pressure during gluing (I don't have any fancy setup to squeeze the handle and cup together so it'd have to be my own two hands for a period between 1 and 5 minutes.
- Requirement for perfect surface fit (there's a chance small flecks chipped off that are lost, so a small fraction of the broken off surface won't fit 100% perfectly together.

Comment: I'm not sure if here or lifehacks is better for this question, please migrate there if more appropriate.

Comment: Unless the handle is hollow (in which case it's impossible to clean and probably gross as a result) there should be no food-contact with a repair to the handle of a ceramic mug.

Comment: Mind you, hit the thrift store and pay a dime, sometimes as much as a quarter is better than gluing, or you could pay real money to a real potter to get a new one, and support your local artists. Dishwasher-safe on ceramic is a tall order (if the chemicals don't kill it the thermal cycling probably will.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about mug repair, not home improvement. Please see the [help/on-topic] for more information.

Comment: https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/631/how-to-glue-mug-pieces might be helpful

Comment: crazy glue would work better if you can get it to permeate the unglazed ceramic before affixing, but it's way messier as well; masking tape/poster putty masks recommended. two part is strong, but thick, maybe too thick to re-flush the glaze chips, and you only get one shot at this fix... i would bake dry the mug, wait for a dry day, and superglue it up, waiting overnight to "dry" (moisten+cure actually) before trying it out.

Answer (score 1):

The one with the biggest advertising budget.

No seriously... 2-part epoxy.

Toxicity -- the inside of your food cans are lined with it,  this is why tomato paste doesn't rust the can.  It can add trace amounts of BPA but only if you botch the mixing heavily toward the B-part.

Dishwasher safety - make sure this epoxy is good up to 100C temperature.  It is impervious to water once cured.

Speed - epoxies come in every imaginable speed from 1 minute to 24 hour cure.

Durability - let's do the math,  epoxy + carbon fiber = Boeing Dreamliner.

Surface fit - not super picky, as it is fairly thick... for better results modify it with a powdered adhesive filler like [West System 404](https://www.westsystem.com/filler-selection-guide/), which can gap narrow imperfections giving full strength. You're supposed to use West System fillers with West system epoxy, but I won't tell.  If you know a boatmaker, ask him for a teaspoon of the stuff.  Mix in til it's like maple syrup, not too much.

I gather you would favor an epoxy on the fast side of the range.  Have a razor knife handy to scrape off any excess, during that sweetspot when it is solid but still rubbery.  It won't be like that for long.